# How can I fix _AssertionError ('dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart' in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I can't fix this error:

```
_AssertionError ('dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart': Failed assertion: line 1919 pos 15: '<optimized out>': is not true.)
```

Code:

```
   final box = await Hive.openBox('principale');

    String _lingua = box.get("locale") ?? "${Localizations.localeOf(context)}";

 
    _locale = Locale(_lingua); // it hangs here

    setState(() {});
```

Can anyone help me fix it?

Comment: Do you got any solution for this @Jonathan ?